# TabHost to launch external browser when clicked

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-tabhost, android-activity

I have some tabs in my app and I want the last tab to launch google in the default system browser. I thought this would work:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/");
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Google", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.google)).setContent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)));
```

But it results in a force close error. Any tips on getting this working?

**EDIT**
I solved this. Basically what I do is add an onClick event handler to capture when the tab is clicked in the first place (only this tab in question) and then from within that I prevent the default action by returning true (for handled) after launching a new Intent in the regular fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start an Activity from Tab Host(that you have mention as last Tab Host).Then from that activity you can launch external Browser.As i think its not possible to launch default activity from TabHost.

**Edited**

I have checked it.It give ActivityNotFound Exception.Conclusion is that TabHost look for the activity that is registered in Android manifest.If you want to achieve it then go with my first suggestion

Comment: what is status of your issue?